# Are there any popular course management system like Moodle?

Tags: java, sakai

I am looking for a java base open source system

Any popular choices?

Answer (score 4):

Google is your friend.

> Free software and open source
>
> - Chamilo
> - Claroline
> - Democrasoft
> - Dokeos
> - eFront
> - ILIAS
> - Moodle
> - Sakai

Source: [Virtual learning environment -> Course management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_learning_environment#Course_management_systems)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's [Sakai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakai_Project)